# Converting a pandas series to string

Tags: python, string, pandas

Here is the data snapshot:

[image]

I want to find the total requests that were made to a page containing a substring 'xxxxx' (assume)

Whenever I try to perform any string operations on page_name variable, it showing the attribute as float and I am getting an error.Here is the error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyo26.png)

I got the data from a csv file. It has 6 million records. Its showing the data type as:
'language' : object ,
'page_name' : object ,
'requests' : int64

I tried to convert it to string using:`english_data['page_name'].astype(basestring)`

That doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot of the dataframe, it would be easier for others to reproduce your issue if you directly copy and paste the data here. Also, please update the code that is throwing the error for you along with the error you are getting.

Comment: It really helps posting actual code than images.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply string methods in a vectorized way using the `str` attribute of `Series`. To find rows in the `'page_name'` column with some string `'xxx'` you can do

```
df.page_name.str.contains('xxx')
```

To get the total number of requests to that page you can do something like

```
df.requests[df.page_name.str.contains('xxx')].sum()
```